# Clicking on the htmlunit button is not responding. Help me

Tags: html, htmlunit

The configuration of the environment is as follows.

java 1.8
htmlunit 2.43

```
        _webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX);
        
        // ajax, javaScript controller
        _webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
                
        // set options
        _webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        _webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        
        _webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        _webClient.getOptions().setSSLClientProtocols( _webClient.getOptions().getSSLClientProtocols() );
        //_webClient.getOptions().setSSLClientProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1" });
        
        _webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);   
        _webClient.getOptions().setPopupBlockerEnabled(false);
        
        _webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        _webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        _webClient.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        
        _webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
        // set timeouts
        _webClient.getOptions().setTimeout( timeout *1000 );
        _webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout( timeout *1000 );
        _webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript( timeout *500 );
        //_webClient.getJavaScriptEngine().setJavaScriptTimeout( timeout *1000 );
        _webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(timeout *1000);

        
        _webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
```

The above is my environment.

Below is the HTML Element I want to click on.

```
<div class="btnConfirmWrap">
  <button data-v-ffa8b1e8=""
    class="hasBgColor bgColorRed roundType sizeMedium alignLeft">
    <span data-v-ffa8b1e8="" class="inner"> <!----> <span
        data-v-ffa8b1e8="" class=""> Login </span>
    <!----></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

This is the code for clicking on the html element mentioned above.
The content of the XPath is the fullXpath of the web page obtained by accessing Chrome.
I checked the XPath path myself. XPath wasn't wrong.

```
hElement = getByXPathFirstElement( _htmlPage,"/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/button");
Page page = hElement.click();
_htmlPage = (HtmlPage) page;
System.out.println(_htmlPage.asText());
```

I checked that _htmlPage.asText() had ID and PW values ​​before clicking the login button.
However, if you click the button, the login button function is not executed and the ID and PW values ​​are lost. ID and password are correct values.
Can't log in, help me
It works very well if you directly access the site and log in. But htmlunit doesn't work. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Without a way to reproduce i can only provide some hints:

As always check the logs, mabey there is a hint....

These two functions are not options

```
_webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript( timeout *500 );
_webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(timeout *1000);
```

You have to call them after you have started an action (e.g. after the click)

```
Page page = hElement.click();
_htmlPage = (HtmlPage) page;
```

Your code gets thy sync resulting page form the click. But maybe you click forces some js actions and maybe the action is async and maybe the action forces a page replace. You can  try to do something like this:

- force the click
- wait for background js
- get the current window content by asking the page for the current window and then asking the window for the enclosed page

Maybe this helps.

If not try to build a reproducible sample and open a issue at github.